# Can't add HTTPS site to Yandex Webmaster Tools

Tags: yandex, yandex-webmaster-tools

I've recently changed a website to run only on HTTPS. HTTP connections are 301 redirected to HTTPS and a HSTS header (`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000`) has been added.

I've added the HTTPS version of the domain to both Google & Bing Webmaster Tools, but when I try to add it to Yandex Webmaster Tools it tells me the site is a mirror:

[image: Yandex add a site]

When I click the "add www.domain.com" link I then get a warning that the site redirects and I should instead add the HTTPS domain, which is what I've already tried:

[image: Yandex add a site warning]

Is there a way around this catch 22?

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran into this same problem a few months back on a site which forces SSL. I contacted Yandex support directly about this so I'll share their response:

> Hello,
>
> Please accept my apologies for the delayed reply.
>
> You should specify https domain as the main mirror in your robots.txt
>   file and then wait for a couple of weeks (
>   http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml#host
>   ). When the main mirror changes according to your settings, your
>   website will be able to start indexing and appear in search results at
>   https protocol. You can find more information about the fact what
>   websites are considered to be mirrors by Yandex on page
>   http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/yandex-indexing/site-mirrors.xml .
>
> -- Sincerely yours, Platon Yandex customer support http://company.yandex.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Yandex have caught on to this and developed a workaround!

[image: Yandex - Add a site]

There's now a new option:

> If the site was mistakenly considered a mirror, you should add
>   https://www.domain.com and adjust the mirrors.

They also recommend using the [Host directive](http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml#host) in `robots.txt` once it's been added.